# How to access or change the value of a variable inside a function which is nested inside another fucntion?

Tags: python-2.7

```
def next1():
    x=1
    def nest2():
       x+=1
       nest2()
    return x
```

When I try to call the fucntion nest1(), it says "local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
". I want to access x which is declared at line 2 inside nest2(). What is the solution?

Comment: in your nested function you havent defined x. you need to pass x to it `def nest2(x):` plus you have an infinite loop in nest2() - it continually calls itself, and never returns a value.

Answer (score 0):

in your nested function you havent defined x. you need to pass x to it `def nest2(x):` plus you have an infinite loop in nest2() - it continually calls itself, and never returns a value.
Why not do it this way? or is there some reason it needs to be nested.

```
def nest2(value): 
    value +=1
    return value   

def next1():
    x=1
    nest2(x)
    return x
```